# How to configure Ubuntu 20.04.5 with static IP addressing?

Tags: networking

I see users of other Ubuntu versions have asked this question, but those answers don't apply here.  I am having the worst time configuring static IP addressing on 20.04.5 from the command line.  Having messed with this so much, I now have a broken 00-installer-config.yaml file contained within /etc/netplan. I am a 25-year networking IT pro, so I'm good with subnetting and being my workplace's network manager.  I am editing the file with nano, and currently the file reads:

```
#This is the network config written by 'subiquity'
network:
  version: 2
  ethernets:
  renderer: networkd
     enp3s0f0: 
       dhcp4: true
     enp3s0f1: 
       dhcp4: true
     enp4s0f0:
       dhcp4: true
```

And I have no good networking connections.  First of all, is there a way to completely reset networking to out-of-the-box status?  I was fine with enp4s0f0 grabbing a DHCP-issued address, but now I have no connections at all.  So the first question is how to restore networking without having to reinstall the OS, and secondly after I have that fixed, how to configure a NIC with static addressing.  I thought I was correctly applying all of the YAML rules regarding spacing (and not tabs), but I always get the following error on random lines:

`Invalid YAML: inconsistent indentation`

My YAML file seems to get rejected no matter what I do.  This forum will not seem to retain my formatting of the YAML, so it's hard for me to post how it currently appears.

Thanks!

Comment: I'd check you've applied all security fixes if your 20.04.5 is correct; a fully upgraded Ubuntu 20.04 LTS system will report itself as 20.04.6 (https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2023/03/23/ubuntu-20-04-6-lts-released/ shows the ISO release date, but installed systems upgraded prior to this date)

Comment: Please see the template at: `cat /usr/share/doc/netplan/examples/static.yaml` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.